# Salesforce 1 for partner users

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I have one requirement in salesforce1 . We have to move to salesforce one from salesforce classic. So what objects will the partner be able to access.
I tried searching but couldn't find. My partners should be able to access lead and opportunity using salesforce one. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce1 doesn't yet support community access.  It is coming in Spring 14, but that will only be for the HTML5 version of the application so your partners would have to login each time.  Record access is no different to the full site - users are able to see the records that are allowed by their license and sharing rules.

There's more information in the HTML release notes at:

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeats_overview.htm